# TwitterKit - how to open iOS twitter app on integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I am using `TwitterKit` for login with `iOS` twitter app. Twitter app is installed in my `iPhone`. Below given code is always open web page to login, but I want to login with twitter app
if anyone have idea to integrate with twitter app , please share.
Thanks

Here is image of error and code1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9yBu.png

`TwitterKit` downloaded from `GitHub` is working properly, I am using same methods, but not able to find what i am missing.

here is screenshot of twitter URI scheme.

[image]

Comment: Did you just read the official document of Twitter SDK here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview/oauth ?

Comment: TwitterKit will be discontinuing support for Twitter Kit on October 31, 2018.  https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios/wiki

Comment: Did you try Twitter URI scheme? In my project, I used that to bring up Twitter app for login.

Comment: Twitter URI scheme is added in URL types.  @RyanB